# Disable links in Dynamics Ax 2012 report viewer

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to disable links in the Ax 2012 report viewer? An example is the PO receipts list report, which has the item numbers as links to the item's details. In Ax4 there was a button to toggle the links on/off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to disable the links from the report viewer, but you can turn them off from the SSRS design.

Open the design, find the text box with the hyperlink you don't want, right click it and go to "Text Box Properties...". Open the Action tab and select the "None" radio button under "Enable as a hyperlink:". Once you rebuild and redeploy the report the hyperlinks will not show up for those text boxes.

[image]